# UIWebview GestureRecognizer for showing a toolbar

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a Webview (inside a view) and a toolbar which is hidden most of the time.

This is quite common behaviour for ipad magazines:
Tapping on the page will hide and display the toolbar, but the toolbar is hidden by default.

I am using shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer

The behaviour right now does this:
- If the user taps the page (webview) it toggles the toolbar state using gesture recognizer
- if the user taps the page and there is an interactive element such as a weblink within the UIWebview, it responds to that interactive link but ALSO toggles the toolbar.

The desired behaviour is this:
- if the user taps the page on a non interactive area, it toggles the toolbar state
- if the user taps the page on an interactive area it ONLY responds to the webview interaction and does NOT toggle the toolbar.

Note there is an almost identical question here:
[Gesture recognition with UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377493/gesture-recognition-with-uiwebview) 
Even though it is marked as resolved if you read it through you will see the solution did not work for the poster and he is still getting a dual response when he (and I) want an either or response. I did try posting a follow up question but that was deleted probably because the moderator believed it was resolved

Answer (score 0):

If the `UIWebView`, for whatever reason, catches the touch, you're not going to be able to get the `UIGestureRecognizer` callback as well. My only recomendation is to make whatever happens in the website when you tap on something execute some javascript, and then catch that Javascript. You can take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525191/uiwebview-respond-to-javascript-calls) as an example.